# Subtract two range values for matching ones excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have come across of the problem that, I don't know how to solve in efficient way. So I have two tables like these:

```
Table 1 
Company   Score
Apple     10 
Banana    5
Kiwi      4 
Pineapple 2

Table 2
Company    Score
Apple      4
Pineapple  3
Kiwi       2
Strawberry 1
```

Then in my result table in which I have company names listed in one column, like below. Right next to this I would like to show the differences which should be the first table values - the second table values where company names match(the list can be in different order that is why, I need to check it before subtracting).

```
Table 3
Company    Result
Kiwi       2
Apple      6
Banana    -5
Pineapple -1
```

I can do this with nested IF function to check every cell one by one, but I assume there might be more efficient way. I wonder if you have one.

Comment: use two sumifs and subtract one from the other.

Comment: Smart, worked thanks.

Comment: @ScottCraner sounds like an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: @elv Please show your formula as an answer, to help anyone who views your question in the future. You can also mention that you solved the problem with the help of @ scott Craner and also mark your answer as answered.

Comment: Of course, will do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ScottCraner's comment, I solved it with two sumifs subtracted from one another with this formula. I entered this in Column D66 and dragged down

```
=SUMIF($C$36:$C$45;$C$66:$C$75;D$36:D$45)-SUMIF($C$51:$C$60;$C$66:$C$75;D$51:D$60)
```

1st Sum if: Where C36-C45 is my first list of companies, C66-C75 is the list of companies that I have in the results table, D36 -D45 is the score list from the first table.

2nd Sum if: Where C51-C60 is my second list of companies, C66-C75 is the list of companies that I have in the results table, D51 -D60 is the score list from the second table.